# 'Pick' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here when trying to extend Pick<

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to have only some properties of *ancestor* exposed on my *descendant*. I try to achieve it through `Pick`

```
export class Base {
    public a;
    public b;
    public c;
}

export class PartialDescendant extends Pick<Base, 'a' |'b'> {
   public y;
}
```

but I receive two errors -

> Error: TS2693: 'Pick' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

and

> Error:TS4020: 'extends' clause of exported class 'PartialDescendant' has or is using private name 'Pick'.

Am I doing something wrong, and is there another way to expose only chosen properties of the base class?

Comment: Base contains less logic then childs. So it seems to be wrong from architecture point of view. You may use mixins or some decorators to add only needed properties to a class.

Comment: In my case, it was happening because the props specified for a component were not optional, and I have not provided those.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**See below for 3.0 solution**

`Pick` is only a type it is not a class, a class is both a type and an object constructor. Types only exist at compile time, this is why you get the error.

You can create a function which takes in a constructor, and returns a new constructor that will instantiate an object with less fields (or at least declare it does):

```
export class Base {
    public c: number = 0;
    constructor(public a: number, public b: number) {

    }
}


function pickConstructor<T extends { new (...args: any[]) : any, prototype: any }>(ctor: T)
    : <TKeys extends keyof InstanceType<T>>(...keys: TKeys[]) => ReplaceInstanceType<T, Pick<InstanceType<T>, TKeys>> & { [P in keyof Omit<T, 'prototype'>] : T[P] } {
    return function (keys: string) { return ctor as any };
}

export class PartialDescendant extends pickConstructor(Base)("a", "b") {
    public constructor(a: number, b: number) {
        super(a, b)
    }
}

var r = new PartialDescendant(0,1);

type IsValidArg<T> = T extends object ? keyof T extends never ? false : true : true;
type ReplaceInstanceType<T, TNewInstance> = T extends new (a: infer A, b: infer B, c: infer C, d: infer D, e: infer E, f: infer F, g: infer G, h: infer H, i: infer I, j: infer J) => infer R ? (
    IsValidArg<J> extends true ? new (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, g: G, h: H, i: I, j: J) => TNewInstance :
    IsValidArg<I> extends true ? new (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, g: G, h: H, i: I) => TNewInstance :
    IsValidArg<H> extends true ? new (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, g: G, h: H) => TNewInstance :
    IsValidArg<G> extends true ? new (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, g: G) => TNewInstance :
    IsValidArg<F> extends true ? new (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F) => TNewInstance :
    IsValidArg<E> extends true ? new (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E) => TNewInstance :
    IsValidArg<D> extends true ? new (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D) => TNewInstance :
    IsValidArg<C> extends true ? new (a: A, b: B, c: C) => TNewInstance :
    IsValidArg<B> extends true ? new (a: A, b: B) => TNewInstance :
    IsValidArg<A> extends true ? new (a: A) => TNewInstance :
    new () => TNewInstance
) : never
```

For constructors parameters you will loose things like parameter names, optional parameters and multiple signatures.

**Edit**

Since the original question was answered typescript has improved the possible solution to this problem. With the addition of [Tuples in rest parameters and spread expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897) we now don't need to have all the overloads for `ReplaceReturnType`:

```
export class Base {
    public c: number = 0;
    constructor(public a: number, public b: number) {

    }
}

type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
function pickConstructor<T extends { new (...args: any[]) : any, prototype: any }>(ctor: T)
    : <TKeys extends keyof InstanceType<T>>(...keys: TKeys[]) => ReplaceInstanceType<T, Pick<InstanceType<T>, TKeys>> & { [P in keyof Omit<T, 'prototype'>] : T[P] } {
    return function (keys: string| symbol | number) { return ctor as any };
}

export class PartialDescendant extends pickConstructor(Base)("a", "b") {
    public constructor(a: number, b: number) {
        super(a, b)
    }
}

var r = new PartialDescendant(0,1);


type ArgumentTypes<T> = T extends new (... args: infer U ) => any ? U: never;
type ReplaceInstanceType<T, TNewInstance> = T extends new (...args: any[])=> any ? new (...a: ArgumentTypes<T>) => TNewInstance : never;
```

Not only is this shorter but it solves a number of problems

- Optional parameters remain optional
- Argument names are preserved
- Works for any number of arguments

Comment: thanks, thats exactly what I was looking for. Could you please point on how I could pass constructor parameters to base class. I am a bit lost looking at the link you gave me

Comment: @Anarion adapted the solution in the link

Comment: @Anarion Fixed the missing statics issue as well.

Comment: There is another way to accomplish this. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little late to the game here, but there is an alternative and shorter way to do it if you're mainly interested in making intellisense work.

You can extend the base class and then redeclare the members you want to omit as private. This will generate a typescript error, but adding //@ts-ignore will clear it up and shouldn't affect compilation.

This is my preferred way to do it when things are simple. No real overhead here or challenging type syntax. The only real downside here is that adding //@ts-ignore above the extending class could prevent you from receiving other error messages related to incorrectly extending the Base class.

The one advantage to this approach over the accepted "pickConstructor" approach is that this method doesn't generate any extra code. Whereas "pickConstructor" literally exists as a function after compilation that runs during class definition.

```js
class Base
{
    public name:string;   
}

// @ts-ignore
class Ext extends Base
{
    private readonly name:undefined; // re-declare
}

let thing:Ext = new Ext();
// The line below...
// Doesn't show up in intellisense
// complains about privacy
// can't be set to anything
// can't be used as an object
thing.name = "test";   // ERROR
```